# Comparing $.post variable in laravel controller to a string for some reason doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

This is my jquery that send data to my laravel controller.

```
$.post(url, { ChatText : ChatText }, function(data) {});
```

Everything works perfect. I can get it with Input::get('ChatText').

But here is the thing I dont understand. When i want to compare Input::get('ChatText'), for example like this:

```
$text = 'test';
$input = Input::get('ChatText');

if($text == $input){

}
```

This for some reason does not work. It only works with numbers. Now after googling i found some post that it has todo with encoding. But i checked and its both UTF-8.

Comment: Are you sure there are no line breaks or other formatting in the string you get from $input?

Comment: Thanks, preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $input); did it for me.

Comment: @sandman Please add an answer to your own question by clicking the *Answer Your Question* button. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

andeersg was correct.

`preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $input);` made it work